In ceedling, Is there a work around for sequential includes in the main file?
I'm working on a C project using Ceedling for unit testing. I have a setup where I include custom data types defined in Types.h in my Main.c file and then include other headers sequentially, assuming they can access those data types indirectly.
For example:
Main.c:
#include "Types.h"  
#include "Functions.h"

  

Functions.h:
u8 sum(u8 x, u8 y);  

test_main.c:
#include"main.h"
#include"mock_functions.h"


In this setup, u8 is defined in Types.h. Normally, Functions.h can use u8 without explicitly including Types.h because Main.c includes Types.h first. However, Ceedling throws an error saying the type u8 is unknown.
Is there a way to configure Ceedling to handle this, or do I need to include Types.h explicitly in Functions.h?
Error:
Generating include list for functions.h...
Creating mock for functions... error: unknown type name 'u8' u8 SUM(u8 x , u8 y);
Notes:

I understand this isn't a good practice, and including dependencies explicitly is generally better. I'm asking if there's a way to make Ceedling work without modifying the headers.

I'm using Ceedling version 0.31.1.


Any advice or explanation would be appreciated!

Is it erroring when compiling main.c or functions.c (assuming sum is not defined in main.c)?

yes ,sum is not in the main.c
it gives an error when compiling the mock_functions.h
for example:
Generating include list for functions.h...
Creating mock for functions...
error: unknown type name 'u8'
u8 SUM(u8 x , u8 y);

So basically I want to create a unit test for main.c and mock functions.h

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, this is not a forum. Please read also "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to add the clarification, in the comments it is overlooked.

Please extend your question (by [edit]ing it) with a [mre] (emphasis on "complete") , the command lines, and the actual error messages, copied verbatim from your console. Please do not use screenshots, even on Windows you can copy the text.

I understand this isn't a good practice, and including dependencies explicitly is generally better. So, what's your fascination with not doing this? Functions.h needs u8 so it should/must include Types.h. Without that, the design is just, well, bad ... What if some other program used #include "Functions.h"? It would bork on compile. Rather than inventing a kludge to get ceedling to fix the defect in Functions.h, just fix the real source of the problem. Then, when generating mock_functions.h from Functions.h, ceedling will see #include "Types.h" and work

If Functions.h [and Types.h] are part of a library, why would you want any programmer using the library/API to need to have incestuous knowledge of the inner workings of the library/API? The only reason that I can think of for your reluctance to do the right thing is that you're not familiar with include guards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

"incestuous knowledge" really now ?
I really appreciate your comment and i do know how guards work ,but in this case I cannot change the source code of the project as stated in the question.
It would have been a more helpful answer if worded a bit better .
Thanks for your time .

Actually, this is not an answer but a comment. Just a hint, to notify @CraigEstey use this form of tag.

@the busybee
Thanks for the hint.

You might be able to do this using the :cmock/:includes directive in your project config file, or something similar. I don't have time to test that right now. There are lots of configurable :cmock fields which seem related to this, e.g. :includes_h_pre_orig_header, :includes_c_pre_header, etc.

Ceedling cannot handle this automatically, this is a bad dependency problem.
You have several solutions here, but the best is to include "Types.h" directly into "Functions.h".
If you really cannot edit the sources for some reason, you can add "Types.h" to your ceedling yaml file under [:cmock][:includes], this option can be used to inject header files into the generated mocks, see documentation.
